# JSON passes null or 0 values on a culture-to-culture basis

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, json

I'm using C# and ASP.NET MVC5. The issue I'm coming across is relatively bizarre.

We have a multilingual website, using a `_culture` cookie for culture storage and changing the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` to reflect the user's culture. The website has a distributor locator on it.

**Here's the issue:**

When using the English language (en-CA in this case), our JSON from the distributor locator is submitted and parsed correctly. When using French (fr), the controller action shows 0.0 for the latitude and longitude, even if it shows a value when parsed in the Chrome devtools console. Radius is seemingly unaffected.

---

jQuery that handles submission:

```
$('.locate-distributors-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    $this = $('.locate-distributors-form');
    e.preventDefault();
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    var address = $('input[name=origin]').val();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latLng = results[0].geometry.location;
            var locationToSubmit = {
                location: {
                    lat: latLng.lat(),
                    lng: latLng.lng()
                },
                radius: $('select[name=radius]').val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: $this.attr('action'),
                type: 'POST',
                data: locationToSubmit,
                success: function(data) {
                    // success function
                }
            });
        } else {
            // error text
        }
    });
})
```

When we pass in, for instance, `"Toronto"`, the `locationToSubmit` object equals:

```
{
  location: {
    lat: 43.653226,
    lng: -79.38318429999998 
  },
  radius: "50"
}
```

The action that is accepting the submission looks like this:

```
public ActionResult LocateDistributors(Location location, int radius = 50)
{
    DistributorLocatorViewModel model = new DistributorLocatorViewModel();
    model.Origin = location;
    model.Distributors = locateDistributors(location, radius);

    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And, finally, the `Location` class is defined as:

```
public class Location
{
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lng { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue has to do with using `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`. This is forcing .NET to expect numbers, etc., to be in the French format. For instance, in English,

```
{
  location: {
    lat: 43.653226,
    lng: -79.38318429999998 
  },
  radius: "50"
}
```

would be correct and would parse server-side correctly.

In French, decimal places are not `.` and are instead `,`, so the aforementioned JSON would therefore need to be:

```
{
  location: {
    lat: '43,653226',
    lng: '-79,38318429999998' 
  },
  radius: "50"
}
```

To circumvent the issue, I'm no longer using `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and am instead using `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`. Doing this, my back-end will expect English-style dates, numbers, and the like, while still displaying things in the user's culture.